# Help proving the countability of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

An interval (x,y) is a set of all Real #'s, such that x < Element < y. If N is a set of intervals, such that no two of the intervals in the set intersect, then prove that N is countable.

I'm not sure how this would be countable, since the set of real numbers isn't. Anyone know how I should approach this proof? I'm guessing it should be with induction, right?

Comment: first you need to distinguish between a set of intervals, and the union of these intervals. The set $\{(1,2),(5,6)\}$ is a set of just two intervals, even though each of these intervals is uncountable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose not. That is, suppose we have uncountably many disjoint intervals. By elementary properties of real numbers, each interval $(x,y)$ must contain a rational number $q$. Since the intervals are disjoint, there means there are uncountably many rational numbers, a contradiction. Therefore, there can be at most countably many such disjoint intervals.

Comment: Why does the fact that there are unaccountably many rational numbers prove there is a contradiction?

Comment: sounds like a well-rehearsed solution ... but only the non-empty intervals $(x,y)$ must contain a rational :) I think the OP has a different difficulty, though

Comment: @Thandor7765 There are only countably many rationals, so saying there are uncountably many is a contradiction.

Comment: ahhhhh, I see. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @Thandor7765 that is not "a fact" that "there are un(ac)countably many rational numbers". The fact is that there are only countably many rationals. The contradiction is that, if there were uncountably many disjoint non-empty intervals $(x,y)$ then we would have been able to pick a rational in each interval, these rationals are different since the intervals are disjoint, and we would have proved there were uncountably many rationals.